# Ubuntu trackpad not working after sleep/suspend

Tags: touchpad

I have a Dell Vostro 5390 whose trackpad will not work in Ubuntu after sleep/suspend. I have tried editing it to not sleep and hibernate instead, but it will still not work. For reference, the driver is Windows Precision when booted in Windows.

Here is the output of lsusb -v, which couldn't be pasted here because too long: https://pastebin.com/sFLU18PS

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Would you please run _lsusb -v_ and copy the resulting text, then come back here, click [edit], and paste the text at the bottom of your question, so all the facts we need are in the question? Please do not use Add Comment which throws away all the formatting, and makes the data harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu <= 18.04, do try this link:

https://sangams.com.np/fix-ubuntu-18-4-touchpad-not-working-properly/